# simple_forms with two classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have one controller for **Property** and other one for **Country** one property has one country

**My Property model**

```
class Property < ApplicationRecord

  acts_as_paranoid

  has_one :country, class_name: Country
  belongs_to :company

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :country

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :address, presence: true
```

**My Country model**

```
class Country < ApplicationRecord

  acts_as_paranoid

  belongs_to :property

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :isoalpha2, presence: true
  validates :isolapha3, presence: true
```

And when I want to add one property with my view (new.html.erb)

```
<%= simple_form_for [@property, @country], url: property_new_path   do |f| %>
    <% if @property.errors.any? %>

            <%= pluralize(@property.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
            this property from being saved:

            <% @property.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li><%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>

    <% end %>
            <%= f.input :name %>
            <%= f.input :description %>
            <%= f.input :address %>

          <%= f.submit %>
```

I receive the following error:

undefined method `description' for #<**Country**:0x8de0b20>

I don't know why is taking the Country class instead of Property , because description is part of the Property controller

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That should be like

```
<%= simple_form_for [ @country, @property] do |f| %>
```

and routes should be in nested form

```
resources :countries do
  resources :properties, except: [:index]
end
```

Hope this will work for you

Comment: Is not working, why is countries ? and why did you change the order first <@>country and later <@>property ?

Comment: First checkout http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources